# Image becomes blurry after resize & $Scale = true in Chrome

Tags: jssor

I'm having an issue where the main slider image and the text of the navigation on the bottom become blurry after resize. On load it is fine, but as soon as you resize the window everything becomes blurry. This is specific to Chrome, other browsers seam fine

Here is an example http://gallery.furnituremix.com/

Here with $scale = false
http://gallery.furnituremix.com/index2.html

Answer (score 0):

It may look blurry if you scale from smaller to bigger size sometimes.

Please make the original size bigger then. You can replace '100px' with '200px', '50px' with '100px'.

```
<div u="slides" style="cursor: move;">
    <div u="prototype" class=p style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 100px; HEIGHT: 50px; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0;">
        <div u="thumbnailtemplate" style="WIDTH: 100px; HEIGHT: 50px; border: none; position: absolute; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0; "></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, I noticed that the original size of the main slider is very small, please make it bigger.

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="margin: 0, auto; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 350px; overflow: hidden; ">
    ...
    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
```